# Some games freezing during startup and using 100% of one CPU core

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, freeze, amd-catalyst

I have a Radeon HD 5870 and Windows 7 with all updates installed. I used 13.4 drivers previously, but upgraded to 13.9 now.

When I start Metro 2033 in DX10 or DX11 mode the game freezes before displaying anything (but already in full screen mode showing nothing but black) and uses 25% of my quad core.

When starting Sleeping Dogs the same thing happens. Pixeljunk Shooter does the same thing too, but in that case already while displaying the splash screen, not after going fullscreen.

Other games like Far Cry Blood Dragon work perfectly fine without any problems.

**Update:**
Far Cry Blood Dragon is doing the same thing now and Sleeping Dogs worked once (after already having had the problem for days), but is having the same problem again now.
I played Blood Dragon nearly daily for a week and it never had any problems.

The only thing I could think of is uninstalling/reinstalling my graphics drivers, but I already did that.

Comment: sounds like hardware may be broken.  Try replacing the graphics adapter with a known good one and report back.

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention this, but Metro 2033 is running just fine in DX9 mode. Highest settings without any artifacting or performance problems.
I do have a 5770 in my other PC, but I always assumed that it was a software problem because in my experience hardware problems either caused a bluescreen, a Windows crash/freeze or artifacting.

Comment: @Robber DX9 games are less resource intensive then DX11 games like sleeping dogs the lag is simply the fact your hardware is having trouble keeping up. Try lowering the settings you can use AMDs CCC tool to change sleeping dogs settings at least try it on the lowest setting

Comment: @Ramhound I'd be very surprised if DX11 actually had a significantly higher overhead than DX9, but even if it had, I have a Haswell i5, 16GB of RAM and (as mentioned in the question) a Radeon HD 5870. If that's not enough to even get into the intro ads of most games something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @Robber - Have you tried to lower the settings of the games in questions?  Some games are CPU intensive, Sleeping Dogs for instance, isn't one of those games.  I will be honest you have a below average GPU.  Its 4 generations behind.  I have a haswell i7 system with 32GB of ram, and one of the best GPUs on the market ( a single step from being the best ), and I am not even able to run Sleeping Dogs on Ultra mode.  Just try my suggestion.

Comment: As I said I managed to actually start it once and it ran at 60-90FPS on highest settings at 1080p. My hardware IS NOT too weak to play these games. Additionally, if it was, I would get a bad framerate. But I can't even get to the menu screen. It just freezes right after starting the game. I'm 100% sure it's a software problem, it's just that I don't want to completely reinstall Windows for something that could potentially be solved in a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried Sleeping Dogs again and it froze (once again) I was staring at my keyboard in frustration and saw the Fraps logo displayed on my G15's LCD. I closed Fraps and suddenly every game started working again. I have no idea why Fraps suddenly stopped working and I'm disappointed I can't see my framerate on my keyboard anymore, but the problem described in the question is solved.